# nginx responses 504/502 gateway timeout error at times

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I faced with a problem.

I have 6 express apps running on Node and use Nginx as a reverse proxy, all of them running without a problem for months. But recently, when I'm trying to navigate to the inner page of any of site it returned me 502 or 504 nginx error.

When I try to run apps on ngrok or locally they work correctly but on the production server, I got 504/502 error.

Nginx log says 
`2019/04/10 16:38:12 [error] 1362#1362: *245 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 37.9.113.120, server: my.server, request: "GET /videos/videoId HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/videos/videoId", host: "www.my.host"`

I tried to increment timeouts

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```

But it didn't help (

Here is my server configuration.

```
server {
    listen x.x.x.x:443 http2;
    ssl on;

    server_name www.myservername.com;

...(ssl conf here)

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I dig on StackOverflow similar topics but didn't find a solution. The most strange thing, in this case, is, after some time inner page is available but after I do loading tests and send about 100 requests on production server it stops working for about half or hour

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're listening on 443, using ssl, you must specify your certificates/key :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /var/lib/nginx/ssl/serverssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/nginx/ssl/serverssl.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8192/;
    }
 }
```

Comment: When you CURL your app directly from the server have you any response ? curl -X GET "http://localhost:3002/"

Comment: unfortunately, curl or wget also didn't respond ((((

Comment: Your app is running on port 3000 or 3002 (nginx log show 3000, nginx conf show 3002) ? Restart your app, then try to curl/wget your app (not nginx!) direclty with 127.0.0.1 and localhost : http://127.0.0.1:3000/videos/videoId , http://localhost:3000/videos/videoId

Comment: If you can't access your app through direct ip/lcoalhost, the problem is on app side not on nginx

Comment: there was a typo error in config. 3000 port is set. just tried to do curl but anyway have same problem. wget or  curl works from my localhost on my machine but not on server.

Comment: Ok, we agree that your node application is launched on your server ? And not on your local machine ? On your server verify that you find your node process with : lsof -i :3000

Comment: Yes, the process exists, the main page loads successfully but when I go to the inner page I get 504 gateway timeout error, time to time it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the original post, I encountered a similar issue. In my case, the problem was in a controller in my Express app. My original code looked like this:

```
export async function someFunction (req: Request, res: Response) {
 // other codes here
   return res.status(202);
}
```

This function doesn't send any response body. It worked fine locally since there was no Nginx involved and this endpoint was only used to receive data from frontend for analysis.

However, when I tried to make a real request to this endpoint from my front-end app to a VM hosting the controller with an Nginx proxy, I would get a 502 or 504 error.

I solved this issue simply by adding a response body when sending the response:

```
export async function someFunction (req: Request, res: Response) {
 // other codes here
   return res.status(202).end();
}
```